# Interactions between non-linear predictors

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, splines, generalized-additive-model

I have data on 70,000 students, nested in 120 schools.  I'm starting with fixed effects for the schools, but at some point I might start letting intercepts and slopes vary.

Some key predictors (e.g. gpa, test scores) have non-linear relationships with some outcomes.  I definitely want to interact these predictors with categorical variables, and maybe with continuous ones as well.  Natural cubic splines might be the right approach, but I haven't seen any examples with interactions or nested data, so I could use some pointers.  These non-linear relationships aren't the sole focus of my research, so I don't want to focus on them to the neglect of other aspects of the model.

I'd appreciate suggestions of R packages, examples of related work, and general advice on how to approach this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try generalized additive mixed models, handily implemented in the [gamm4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamm4/index.html) package. The way I've used them, you can do something like:

```
fit1 = gamm4(
    formula = V1 ~ V2 + s(V3)
    , random = ~ (1|V4)
)
fit2 = gamm4(
    formula = V1 ~ V2 + s(V3,by=V2)
    , random = ~ (1|V4)
)
```

`fit1` seeks to predict V1 using V4 as a random effect and V2 and V3 as fixed effects, but where V3 is spline-smoothed. `fit2` seeks the same, except with the addition of permitting the smooth of V3 to vary within levels of V2, thus implementing an interaction. Comparison of `fit1` to `fit2` evaluates the necessity of permitting the interaction.

Comment: Package recommendations: **amer** — Additive mixed models with lme4, **gamm4** — Generalized additive mixed models using mgcv and lme4, **mgcv** (gamm function, via glmmPQL in MASS package), from [here](glmm.wikidot.com/faq)